# How to read stderr from the process running in the background?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, read, stderr

I wanna send the daemon into the background and only continue my script execution when the daemon outputs the particular line to the stderr, something among the lines:

```
# Fictional daemon
{
    for x in {1..9}; do
        sleep 1
        if [ "$x" != "5" ]; then
            echo $x 1>&2
        else
            echo now 1>&2
        fi
    done
} &

# Daemon PID
PID="$!"

# Wait until the particular output... 
until { read -r line && grep -q "now" <<<"$line"; } do 
    sleep 1
done </proc/$PID/fd/2

#
# Do more stuff...
#

fg
```

Answer (score 3):

With a `mydaemon` that behaves like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
i=1 stage=init
while true; do
  if [ "$i" -eq 5 ]; then
    echo >&2 ready
    stage=working
  fi
  echo >&2 "$stage $i"
  sleep 1
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

That is, which takes 4 seconds to initialise, outputs `ready` when ready an carries on working from then all in the same process, you could write a `start-mydaemon` script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
DAEMON=./mydaemon
LOGFILE=mydaemon.log
umask 027

: >> "$LOGFILE" # ensures it exists
pid=$(
  sh -c 'echo "$$"; exec "$0" "$@"' tail -fn0 -- "$LOGFILE" | {
    IFS= read -r tail_pid
    export LOGFILE DAEMON
    setsid -f sh -c '
      echo "$$"
      exec "$DAEMON" < /dev/null >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1'
    grep -q ready
    kill -s PIPE "$tail_pid"
  }
)
printf '%s\n' "$DAEMON started in process $pid and now ready"
```

```
$ time ./start-mydaemon
./mydaemon started in process 230254 and now ready
./start-mydaemon  0.01s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 4.029 total
$ ps -fjC mydaemon
UID          PID    PPID    PGID     SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
chazelas  230254    6175  230254  230254  0 10:28 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh - ./mydaemon
```

`start-mydaemon` doesn't return until `mydaemon` has indicated that it was ready. Here, `mydaemon`'s stdout and stderr goes to a logfile, while its stdin is redirected from `/dev/null`. `setsid -f` (not a standard command but found on most Linux distributions) should guarantee the daemon is detached from the terminal (if started from one).

Note however that if `mydaemon` fails to initialise and dies without ever writing `ready`, that script will wait forever for a `ready` that will never come (or will come the next time `mydaemon` is started successfully).

Also note that `sh -c ...tail` and the daemon are started simultaneously. If `mydaemon` has already initialised and printed `ready` by the time `tail` has started and seeked to the end of the log file, `tail` will miss the `ready` message.

You could address those problems with something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
DAEMON=./mydaemon
LOGFILE=mydaemon.log
export DAEMON LOGFILE
umask 027

died=false ready=false canary_pid= tail_pid= daemon_pid=
: >> "$LOGFILE" # ensures it exists
{
  exec 3>&1
  {
    tail -c1 <&5 5<&- > /dev/null # skip to the end synchronously
    (
      sh -c 'echo "tail_pid=$$" >&3; exec tail -fn+1' |
        { grep -q ready && echo ready=true; }
    ) <&5 5<&- &
  } 5< "$LOGFILE"
  setsid -f sh -c '
    echo "daemon_pid=$$" >&3
    exec "$DAEMON" < /dev/null 3>&- 4>&1 >> "$LOGFILE" 2>&1' 4>&1 |
      (read anything; echo died=true) &
  echo "canary_pid=$!"
} | {
  while
    IFS= read -r line &&
      eval "$line" &&
      ! "$died" &&
      ! { [ -n "$daemon_pid" ] && "$ready" ; }
  do
    continue
  done
  if "$ready"; then
    printf '%s\n' "$DAEMON started in process $daemon_pid and now ready"
  else
    printf >&2 '%s\n' "$DAEMON failed to start"
  fi
  kill -s PIPE "$tail_pid" "$canary_pid" 2> /dev/null
  "$ready"
}
```

Though that's starting to be quite convoluted. Also note that since `tail -f` is now operating on stdin, on Linux, it will not use inotify to detect when new data is available in the file and resort to the usual *check every second* which means it may take up to one extra second to detect `ready` in the log file.

Comment: What is fd 4 used for and why are you redirecting it?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> ...
> done </proc/$PID/fd/2
> ```

That doesn't work as you think it does.

The stderr of `$PID` is either

- the controlling tty, in which case you will try to read a string entered by the user at what it's probably also the *stdin* of `$PID`
- a pipe -- you would compete with whomever is already reading from it, resulting in a complete messup
- `/dev/null` -- EOF!
- something else ;-) ?

---

There are only hacky ways to redirect elsewhere a file descriptor from a running process, so your best bet is to have your input-waiting code downgrade itself into a `cat >/dev/null` running in the background.

For instance, this will "wait" until the daemon outputs `4`:

```
% cat /tmp/daemon
#! /bin/sh
while sleep 1; do echo $((i=i+1)) >&2; done

% (/tmp/daemon 2>&1 &) | (sed /4/q; cat >/dev/null &)
1
2
3
4
%
```

After which `/tmp/daemon` will continue writing to `cat >/dev/null &`, outside the control of shell.

Another solution would be to redirect the stderr of the daemon to some regular file and `tail -f` on it, but then the daemon will go on filling your disk with garbage (even if you `rm` the file, the space it occupies won't be freed until the daemon closes it), which is even worse than having a low-resource `cat` loitering around.

Of course, the best thing will be to write `/tmp/daemon` as a real daemon, which backgrounds itself after initializing, closes its std file descriptors, uses `syslog(3)` for printing errors, etc.

Comment: `for` loop is here just to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve. In fact I have RabbitMQ binary, which I need to start first and then initialize the internal state of it by connecting to it using cli app. If I send it to the background my init scripts starts running too early, when the server is not ready yet to accept connections. I know I could just sleep for a certain number of seconds, but I wanna be a bit smarter :-)

Comment: So it's my `/tmp/daemon`. Just for illustration. I don't see what difference that makes. The `sed /now/q` is just a nicer way for writing your `while ... read ... grep -q` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers involve using files or named pipes.  You don't need either.  A simple pipe is enough.

```
#!/bin/bash

run_daemon() {
    # Fictional daemon
    {
        for x in {1..9}; do
            sleep 1
            if [ "$x" != "5" ]; then
                echo $x 1>&2
            else
                echo now 1>&2
            fi
        done
    }
}

run_daemon 2>&1 | (

    exec 9<&0 0</dev/null

    while read -u 9 line && test "$line" != now
    do
        echo "$line"    ## or ## :
    done
    echo "$line"        ## or ##
    cat /dev/fd/9 &     ## or ## cat /dev/fd/9 >/dev/null &

    #fictional stuff
    for a in 1 2 3
    do
        echo do_stuff $a
        sleep 1
    done
    echo done

    wait
)
```

The sections marked `## or ##` are alternatives if you don't want to show the daemon's output mixed in.  Note that you can't omit the cat because it is the only thing preventing the daemon getting a SIGPIPE when it outputs.

I tried not redirecting the input to a different file descriptor (the `exec`), but without that something closes the input and the daemon terminates.

You may also note that I made the daemon not explicitly backgrounded.  With the pipe, it isn't needed.  The `wait` waits for the cat, not the daemon.  It still works if the daemon is backgrounded.

`wait` is analogous to `fg`, but doesn't make the console controlling.  (It is also much older.)

Answer (score 0):

`mkfifo` can do what you need. See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43949166/reading-value-of-stdout-and-stderr

> Use a FIFO Instead
>
> Technically, /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr are really
>   file descriptors, not FIFOs or named pipes. On my system, they're
>   actually just symlinks to /dev/fd/1 and /dev/fd/2. Those descriptors
>   are typically linked to your TTY or PTY. So, you can't really read
>   from them the way you're trying to do.

This code does what you're looking for (I removed the processing steps). No sleep is necessary in the loop that reads. Note that when the code reading from the fifo has stopped, the daemon will continue to try writing into it until it fills up and the daemon will block until something reads from the fifo.

```
fifo="daemon_errors"
{
    mkfifo $fifo
    for x in {1..9}; do
        sleep 1
        if [ "$x" != "5" ]; then
            echo $x 1>&2
        else
            echo now 1>&2
        fi
    done 2>$fifo
} &

sleep 1 # need to wait until the file is created

# Read all output 
while read -r line; do
    echo "just read: $line"
done < $fifo
```

Comment: when the code reading from the fifo has stopped, the daemon will continue to try writing into it until it fills up and the daemon will block until something is going to read from the fifo.